# Is there any way to be notified when another process receives a signal?

Tags: unix, signals

I know how a process can respond to signals that were sent to it specifically (e.g. `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGUSR2`, etc.).  But can a process be notified of signals that were sent to a different process?

Comment: Why do you ask? Please **edit your question** to motivate it. Smells like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I'm not a fan of the recent attention the XY problem has received. Unlike your very helpful answer below, many SO users are quick to dismiss the OP's question, and instead jump to the conclusion that the OP just doesn't have a clue.  Sure, sometimes extra motivation in the OP question *can* clarify things, but that needs to be balanced with the merits of a short, succinct, and clear question.  This question is short and clear, and your answer is on-topic and well-written. Future readers will waste no time understanding what was written here today, and whether it applies to their situation.

Comment: I'm sure you have some additional goals (or motivation) in mind. You surely have already read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Mentioning them in a sentence (or a few of them) would improve *a lot* your question (which IMHO is too short). **Why do you ask?**

Comment: For example, many questions involving multi-threading in Python quickly receive a response along the lines of "Don't use threading in Python... because GIL." These answers are unhelpful and actually incorrect in many cases.  (Most numerical processing libraries release the GIL, so threading is the most efficient way to achieve parallelization.)  It's so frustrating to read answers that amount to "You don't know what you're doing, use multiprocessing instead" when the responders are the clueless ones!

Comment: But that does not improve your question. The comment above should go to meta, and is not related to your question at all. I'm expecting you to avoid commenting your own question (since you have already 6K points here, so you know the habits here)

Comment: I wasn't hoping for an answer to my specific problem.  Independent of my specific problem, this seemed like a reasonable question to ask, of general interest to unix programmers.  (I briefly looked at the man page for signal before asking for help, but I didn't find a conclusive answer.)  The general motivation for my question is: "I would like to be educated on this subject, and I know there are helpful experts out there who might be willing to help." (Again, thanks very much for your answer!)

Comment: But if you are volunteering to dig into the details of the situation that inspired this curiosity, that is above-and-beyond what I had hoped for.  Thanks very much if this is the case, but if not, I completely understand.

Comment: I have now explained the motivating situation as independent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226441/can-a-parent-process-determine-if-its-child-has-received-a-sigint

Comment: Thank you, kind sir, for acceding to my point in this constructive little discussion. To recap: I made a deliberate decision not to motivate my question because (1) the question as-is stands on its own and (2) the motivation would be nuanced and distracting. You kindly acknowledged not one, but *both* points by (1) giving a top-notch answer below, and (2) down-voting my follow-up question as "unclear" -- and then voting to close it!  I would have been perfectly satisfied without the latter, but I guess you wanted to emphasize your agreement regarding point 2. You personify this site perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in standard Unix or POSIX, you cannot be notified for signals sent to another process. See [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

However, [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and friends can tell you if a [*child process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) has terminated with a signal. And [killpg(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html) sends a signal to a [*process group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) (and [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) does also that with a negative target pid). And [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) can count signals (recieved by some other process). You could also use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) to query information about other processes. And you might use [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) or [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) etc....

Signals are a very limited and poor form of [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). There are better ways.

BTW, [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) can be used with `SA_SIGINFO` and then your handler gets a pointer to `siginfo_t` and another to  `ucontext_t` so you get a lot of information.

Notice that process groups and sessions are related. See also [setpgid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html), [setsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and also related to terminals and pseudo-ttys (read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and about [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix))).

<sup>I guess that your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47226441/841108) question is about these. But you don't mention any of them there.</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive answer, this is very useful information.

Comment: Could you then improve your question to motivate it?