# Can a parent process determine if its child has received a SIGINT?

Tags: unix, subprocess, signals

Suppose, I launch a parent process, which launches a subprocess, but then the parent receives a `SIGINT`. I want the parent to exit, but I don't want the child process to linger and/or become a zombie. I need to make sure it dies.

If I can determine that the child also received a `SIGINT`, then it is probably cleaning up on its own.  In that case, I'd prefer to briefly wait while it finishes and exits on its own. But if it did not receive a `SIGINT`, then I will send it a `SIGTERM` (or `SIGKILL`) immediately and let the parent proceed with its own cleanup.

How can I figure out if the child recevied the `SIGINT`? (Leaving aside the fact that it might not even respond to `SIGINT`...)  Do I just have to guess, based on whether or not the parent is running in the foreground process group?  What if the `SIGINT` was sent programmatically, not via `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: How was the `SIGINT` done? Ctrl-C is generally given to a process group....

Comment: Unclear question. Give an [MCVE]

Comment: Related question (by same OP): https://stackoverflow.com/q/47224241/841108

Comment: No, unless said SIGINT directly kills the child, in which case the parent will get SIGCHLD anD the status the parent will be able to receive for the child via `waitpid` will indicate the child was killed by SIGINT.

Also, a child won't become a zombie if its parent dies. A child will become a zombie if it dies and its parent doesn't reap its status information

Answer (score 0):

> How can I figure out if the child received the SIGINT?

Perhaps you can't. And what should matter to you is if the child *handled* `SIGINT` (it could have ignored it). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47224374/841108) to your other question.

However, in many cases, the signal sent by <kbd>Ctrl C</kbd> was sent to a process group. Then you might have got that signal too.

In pathological cases, your entire system experiments [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) and the child process had not even being scheduled yet to process the signal.

> I want the parent to exit, but I don't want the child process to linger and/or become a zombie. I need to make sure it dies.

Maybe you want to use somewhere [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) ?

<sup>BTW, I don't understand your question, because I have to guess its (ungiven) motivations. Are you caring about job control or implementing a shell? In what concrete cases do you really care that the child got the `SIGINT` and what does that mean to you?</sup>